# Asking your question from another site

Tags: discussion, duplicates, asking-questions

If you asked a puzzle like question about a specific topic (such as a puzzle about math on the mathematics site, or Chess on the Chess site) and it wasn't received well, is it alright to still ask it here? Or is it a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like, you can flag the post for moderator attention, so that a moderator on that site can migrate the post to Puzzling. Answers and comments will stay, but votes will be reset if the post had a negative score.

However, please don't cross-post your question, i.e. post it on multiple sites *at the same time*. (I know this isn't what you're asking; I'm saying this only for future readers.) See [the Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/180276) for more information on this topic.